# Adding focus to a spinner by mouseover mousewheel

Tags: java, focus, spinner, mousewheel

I want to make a spinner which gets focus by moving the cursor over it and then using mouse wheel. How can you do that with a FocusEvent?

Im looking forward for your advice.

Greetings

Comment: Do any other spinners in any of the other applications on the user’s system behave that way?  If they don’t, why would you want to surprise a user like that?  Generally, it is not a good idea to make standard controls behave in unexpected ways.

Comment: I'm trying to make three spinners for enter a code combination (0-9) like a safe. So if one spinner has focus, the other spinners are only allowed to show a * but not the number. The numbers can be changed by keyboard and also by mousewheel. So besides clicking it, I want the spinner to get focus by using the mousewheel, otherwise the spinner does not has focus and all spinners are showing numbers but not *.

Comment: I think you may want to create a custom component for that, rather than trying to coerce a standard spinner component into such behavior.  Or, of course, just use standard spinners and let the standard focus model work as it normally does.